# Give an example of a closed set that not all its elements are limit points

Tags: real-analysis

From the definition, a closed set contains all its limit points. But how can a closed set that not all its elements are limit points? My example is $S=\{1/n\}$.

Comment: Closed in what? In your example, the set $S$ is closed in $(0,\infty)$ but not in $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: You need to adjoint $0$ to your set for it to be closed. Then the example works. $0$ is the only limit point of $S$, so since closed if and only if contains all limit point you want $0\in S.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example does **not** work, if I understand it correctly (I presume you actually mean $S=\{{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$): $0$ is a limit point of $S$, but isn't in $S$, so $S$ is not closed. If we add $0$ to $S$, we get something that works *(since e.g. ${1\over 42}$ is in the set but not a limit point of the set - indeed, *every* element of this set, other than $0$, is a non-limit-point element!)*, but in fact we can do much simpler: $\{17\}$, for example, is closed *(in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$)* and has no limit points.

Answer (score 1):

$S=\{\frac 1n|n \in \mathbb N\}$ is not closed.  It has a limit point $0$ and $0 \not \in S$.  But $S\cup \{0\}$ is  a fine example.  So is $\mathbb N$ itself. Or a set with singletons:  $\{1,3\}$.  Or a combination: $[0,1]\cup \{2\}$.

"But how can a closed set that not all its elements are limit points?"

A closed set contains all of its limit points;  but that doesn't mean that the limit points are the only points it has.

Consider $\{\frac 1n\}\cup \{0\}$  It has one limit point: $0$ and $0$ is in the set.  So all of its limit points are in the set.  So it is closed.  All the rest of the points that aren't limit points?  They have nothing to do with anything.

Note.  If a set doesn't have *any* limit points at all, such as $\mathbb N$ then is is closed by default.  It doesn't have any limit points so all of its limits points are in the set (because there aren't any).

Answer (score 0):

S is not a closed set, but you can use $S\cup \{0\}$. Or simply a finite set for instance $\{1,2\}$.